# Azure Data Factory Copy Data from API Error

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

Using Azure Data Factory, I need to get data from an API into the database. I'm getting the following error from the copy data activity in ADF. It is strange when I use a web activity, I receive a valid response, but I can't copy the data into the database with a web activity. For some reason the copy data activity is getting an error while the web activity is not.

`Failure happened on 'Source' side. ErrorCode=UserErrorFailToReadFromRestResource,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=An error occurred while sending the request.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException,Message=An error occurred while sending the request.,Source=mscorlib,''Type=System.Net.WebException,Message=The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.,Source=System,''Type=System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException,Message=The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.,Source=System,'`

Comment: It looks like this is an issue with the SSL cert on the API side. I'd guess that the copy activity must attempt some sort of validation while the web activity does not. I'm not aware of any way of overriding this validation. Fix the cert on the API side.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message states, the certificate validation failed while establishing the connection for the SSL/TLS channel. You can try reinstalling the certification.

1. In **`Web activity`**, you might have the **disabled** certificate validation property (default this property is disabled in web activity). So it did not validate the cert and got the repose.

[image]

2. In **`Copy data`** activity, when you create source dataset with **Rest linked service**, server certificate validation property is **enabled** by default. So there are chances the error occurred while validating the certificate if it is invalid. You can try disabling the Server Certificate Validation in Rest linked service.

[image]